# React - <Link> tag displays the dynamic url in browser but does not render the page unless the browser is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newbie trying to build a React blog. Routes etc work fine except when a dynamic route comes into question. The Link does not render unless refreshed.

Here is App.js where the Routes are defined

```
function App() {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
    <Router history={customHistory}>
      <div className="App">
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ username, setUsername, loggedIn, setLoggedIn }}>
          <Navigation />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/blog/:id" component={BlogDetails} />
            <Route path="/content" component={Content} />
            <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </div>
    </Router>
    </>
  )
}
export default App;
```

**Here is BlogItems.js which calls the :**

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function BlogItems() {

```
const [blogList, setBlogList] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get"
        , { withCredentials: true })
        .then((res) => {
            setBlogList(res.data);
        });
}, []);

return (
    <div className="blog-list">
        {blogList && blogList.map((blog) => {
            return (
                <div className="blog-elems" key={blog && blog.id}>
                    <Link to={`/blog/${blog.id}`}>{blog.title}</Link>
                    <h6>By <span>Ritu Rawat</span> on {DateFormater(blog.dated)}</h6>
                    <div className="blog-list-body">{blog && blog.body.slice(0, 200) + '...'}</div>
                </div>
            );
        })}
    </div>
) }
```

export default BlogItems;

**and this is the actual BLogDetails Page which needs to be called from the dynamic route:**

```
const BlogDetails = (props) => {
        console.log(props);
        //const { username } = useContext(UserContext);
        const [blog, setBlog] = useState(null);
        const { id } = useParams();
    
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log("BLOG ARTICLE");
            Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/blog/${id}`
                , { withCredentials: true })
                .then((res) => {
                    setBlog(res.data[0]);
                });
        }, [id]);
    
        return (
            <>
                <div className="blog-background">
                    <div className="blog-list">
                        <div className="blog-elems" key={blog && blog.id}>
                            <h2> {blog && blog.title}</h2>
                            <h6>By <span>Ritu Rawat</span> on {blog && DateFormater(blog.dated)}</h6>
                            <div className="blog-list-body">{blog && blog.body}</div>
                        </div>
                        <Comments id={id} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
    
    export default BlogDetails;
```

Comment: I think your `Link` needs to be inside of a component rendered by the router

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and moved the <Link> from BlogItems.js file to the Content.js file.                                                                                                        
 <Route exact path="/blog/:id" component={BlogDetails} />
 <Route path="/content" component={Content} />  //moved the BlogItems.js code to this Content.js file, but the same problem persists.